# How to launch application from web browser on Windows and macOS?

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, browser

I have seen how apps like `Zoom` launch their application on desktop whenever we click `Join Meeting` on the browser. I am unable to figure out how to do that. I tried putting the link of the app as *`URL`* but that just started downloading the application. I just need to open the app and do nothing else. Is there any way to implement that using `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom URI Scheme will help you to achieve this for your app.
For eg: zoommtg, zoomus schemes are used by Zoom
example: Windows/Mac client: zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno=123456789&pwd=xxxx&zc=0&browser=chrome&uname=Betty

iOS/Android Client: zoomus://zoom.us/join?confno=123456789&pwd=xxxx&zc=0&browser=chrome&uname=Betty

Answer (score 3):

You should learn about how to write a custom URI scheme, define it in your app. and then, trigger it in the browser instead `https://`.
Check it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes